# Check if member is in a Voice Channel discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, discord.js

How can one check if a specific member is in any voice channel using discord.js v13? I have only found answers which are about discord.js v12 but no newer answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GuildMember.voice`.

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/v13/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=voice

```js
if (member.voice.channelId) {
  console.log('User is in voice channel!')
}
```